# Do there exist positive integers $m$, $n$, $p$, $q$ such that $m>1$, $p\neq q$, $p$ and $q$ divide $mn^2 - 1$, and $mn$ divides $p - q$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

Do there exist positive integers $m$, $n$, $p$, $q$ such that $m>1$, $p\neq q$, $p$ and $q$ divide $mn^2 - 1$, and $mn$ divides $p - q$?

It seems numerically up to $n \leq  10^6$ that for $m=3$ or $m=4$, such a triplet $(p,q,n)$ satisfying the conditions does not exist. The case of $m=2$ was answered negatively at [MathSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4872586/).

Comment: By dividing $p$ and $q$ by their greatest common divisor, we may assume that $p$ and $q$ are coprime. If we write $p=q+kmn$ and $mn^2-1=pqr=q(q+kmn)r$, then the question is whether the equation $mn^2-q^2r-kmnqr=1$ has any positive integer solutions with $m>1$.

Comment: When viewed as a quadratic form in $n$ and $q$, there might be not be any congruence obstruction. For example, the equation $3x^2-11y^2-33xy=1$ has no integer solutions, but has a solution modulo every positive integer due to the rational solutions $(1/5,-1/5)$ and $(4/13,-1/13)$.

Comment: My original argument was only complete for $m\neq\square$. Now the argument is complete for the exceptional case $m=\square$ as well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I will show below that there are no solutions. I will use the ideas of Denis Shatrov from the [MSE page](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4872586/) along with [Keith Conrad's notes](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/ugradnumthy/pelleqn2.pdf) about the Pell equation. I will also use some ideas from comments by Thomas Browning. (Meanwhile, Thomas Browning found a more direct proof.)

Let $(m,n,p,q)$ be a tuple satisfying the conditions. Without loss of generality, $p$ and $q$ are coprime, and $p<q$. Hence $q=p+mnt$ for some integer $t>0$. Now $pq$ divides $mn^2-1$, hence for some integer $s>0$ we have
$$mn^2-1=sp(p+mnt).$$
Equivalently,
$$mn^2-s p^2=1+mnpst.\tag{1}$$
In particular, $mn^2>mnpst$, whence $n>pst$. Now we consider the positive integers
$$d:=m(ms^2t^2+4s),\qquad r:=m(2n-pst),\qquad u:=mst^2+2.\tag{2}$$
It is straightforward that $d\neq\square$ and $d\equiv 0,1\pmod{4}$, hence $d$ is a positive discriminant. Let us denote by $\mathcal{O}$ the ring of integers of the real quadratic field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$. Observing that
$$r^2-dp^2=4m\qquad\text{and}\qquad u^2-dt^2=4,$$
we infer that $\xi:=(r+p\sqrt{d})/2$ and $\epsilon:=(u+t\sqrt{d})/2$ are totally positive elements of $\mathcal{O}$ of norms $m$ and $1$, respectively. Multiplying $\xi$ by a suitable integral power of $\epsilon$, we obtain a totally positive element $(x+y\sqrt{d})/2\in\mathcal{O}$ of norm $m$ such that
$$\sqrt{m/\epsilon}\leq\frac{x-y\sqrt{d}}{2}\leq\frac{x+y\sqrt{d}}{2}\leq\sqrt{m\epsilon}.$$
It follows that
$$0\leq y<\sqrt{\frac{m\epsilon}{d}}<\sqrt{\frac{mu}{d}}=\sqrt{\frac{mst^2+2}{ms^2t^2+4s}}<1.$$
As $y$ is an integer, it must be zero, and hence $m=\square$. Denoting $k:=\sqrt{m}$, which is an integer exceeding $1$, the original equation $(\ast)$ becomes
$$(kn)^2-s p^2=1+(kn)ps(kt).$$
This is the same equation as $(1)$, but with $(1,kn,kt)$ in place of $(m,n,t)$. So we are left with showing that $(1)$ has no positive integer solution $(m,n,p,s,t)$ with $m=1$ and $\gcd(n,t)>1$.

Let $(m,n,p,s,t)$ be a positive integer solution of $(1)$ with $m=1$. We need to show that $\gcd(n,t)=1$. Using the notations of the previous paragraph, we conclude that $(x+y\sqrt{d})/2=1$. That is, $\xi$ is an integral power of $\epsilon$. In other words, either $(r+p\sqrt{d})/2$ or $(r-p\sqrt{d})/2$ can be written as $\epsilon^j$ with an integer $j\geq 0$. Note that $r>2$ by $n>pst$, whence $j>0$.
In particular, by the binomial theorem,
$$2^{j-1}r=\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor j/2\rfloor}\binom{j}{2i}u^{j-2i}t^{2i}d^i.\tag{3}$$
Assume first that $d\equiv 1\pmod{4}$. Then $t$ and $u$ are odd by $(2)$, hence it follows from $(2)$ and $(3)$ that
$$\gcd(n,t)=\gcd(2n,t)=\gcd(r,t)=\gcd(2^{j-1}r,t)=\gcd(u^j,t)=\gcd(2^j,t)=1.$$
Assume now that $d\equiv 0\pmod{4}$.
Then $st$ and $r$ and $u$ are even by $(2)$. We claim that $ps$ is also even. Indeed, if $s$ is odd, then $t$ is even, hence $\epsilon\in\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$, and therefore $\epsilon^j\in\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$, and $p$ is even. Hence both $r$ and $ps$ are even, and then it follows from $(2)$ and $(3)$ that
$$\gcd(n,t)=\gcd(r/2,t)=\gcd((u/2)^j,t)=1.$$
So in all cases we have that $\gcd(n,t)=1$, and the proof is complete.

Comment: thank you for this clear and detailed proof

Comment: Could you please explain how you got $0 < y$? I only see $0 \le y$...

Comment: @AlekseiKulikov You are right, there is a gap here. If $m\neq\square$, then $y\neq 0$, hence the argument is fine. If $m=\square$, then the argument is incomplete. I updated my post accordingly, and I will think about the remaining case as time permits. Others are welcome to think about this as well.

Comment: Is this notation for "square number" standard? I have never seen that before...

Comment: @SamHopkins It is pretty standard in number theory. See e.g. the second page of Heath-Brown: A mean value estimate for real character sums, Acta Arith. 72 (1995), 235–275. The paper is available at https://bibliotekanauki.pl/articles/1391309.pdf

Comment: If $m=d^2$ is a square, then you can replace $m$ by $1$, $n$ by $dn$, and $t$ by $dt$. So the question becomes whether there are any solutions to $n^2-sp^2=1+npst$ with $\gcd(n,t)>1$. Or $x^2-stxy-sy^2=1$ with $\gcd(x,t)>1$. This generalized Pell's equation is periodic under the map $(x,y)\mapsto((st^2+1)x+sty,tx+y)$ which preserves $x\pmod{t}$. So the question is just whether there are any solutions between $(x,y)=(1,0)$ and $(x,y)=(st^2+1,t)$.

Comment: Ah, I think I have it. If $x^2-stxy-sy^2=1$, then solving for $x$ gives $x=\frac{1}{2}(sty\pm\sqrt{s^2t^2y^2+4(sy^2+1)})$. In particular, the discriminant $s^2t^2y^2+4(sy^2+1)$ must be a perfect square. If $0<y<t$, then $(sty)^2<s^2t^2y^2+4(sy^2+1)<(sty+2)^2$. This forces $s^2t^2y^2+4(sy^2+1)=(sty+1)^2$ which gives a contradiction mod $2$.

Comment: @ThomasBrowning I completed my argument differently, in the style of my original argument for $m\neq\square$. I will study your shorter complete solution later.

Comment: @GHfromMO If m is a square, so you have the new equation $n^2-tsnp-sp^2=1$, it is possible to use the explicit continued fraction for $\sqrt{D}$ to show that $t|p$ for all possible solutions. I wonder if you can simplify your solution by proving the stronger $t|p$ instead of $(n,t)=1$? Note further that $n\equiv 1 \mod t$ is also actually true.

Comment: @IvanMeir I don't want to think about my solution any more, because Thomas Browning found the "proof from the book". See my 3 comments below his post, starting with "I think the best way to tell this story is as follows." In particular, the smallest positive value of $ax^2−abcxy−cy^2$ over $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$ equals $a$, which is a much stronger statement than to say that $1$ is not a value.

Comment: @GHfromMO I quite understand, thanks for taking the time to reply. It was interesting to me though to see proofs from different perspectives and Thomas Browning's argument, though very elegant, does rely on finding the equation preserving map which, to me at least, was quite a leap!

Comment: @IvanMeir Yes, but note that the existence of the automorphism $T$ (of infinite order) was known, the only question is why that $T$ is so effective in the current situation. I also agree that it is good to look at the problem from many angles, I just have a limited amount of time.

Answer (score 8):

I'll first give a quick summary of this solution, and then fill in the details of each step below.

1. It suffices to show that if $a>1$, $b$, and $c$ are positive integers, then there are no integral points on the $x>0$ branch of the hyperbola $ax^2-abcxy-cy^2=1$.
2. The linear transformation $T:(x,y)\mapsto((ab^2c+1)x+bcy,abx+y)$ in $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ acts on the $x>0$ branch of the hyperbola and maps integral points to integral points.
3. Every point of $x>0$ branch of the hyperbola can be mapped by a (possibly negative) power of $T$ to a point satisfying $0<x\leq a^{-1/2}$.
4. If $a>1$, then there are no integral points satisfying $0<x\leq a^{-1/2}$, so there are no integral points on the $x>0$ branch of the hyperbola.

In fact, the arc of the hyperbola between $(a^{-1/2},-a^{1/2}b)$ and $(a^{-1/2},0)$ is a fundamental domain for the action of $T$ on the $x>0$ branch of the hyperbola, but we will not need to prove this.

---

1. By dividing $p$ and $q$ by their greatest common divisor, we may assume that $p$ and $q$ are coprime. We may also assume that $p>q$. Now write $p=q+kmn$ and $mn^2-1=pqr=(q+kmn)qr$ for positive integers $k$ and $r$. Then we must show that the equation
   $$mn^2-kmnqr-q^2r=1$$
   has no positive integer solutions with $m>1$.
   After relabeling variables, it suffices to show that if $a>1$, $b$, and $c$ are positive integers, then there are no integral points on the $x>0$ branch of the hyperbola
   $$ax^2-abcxy-cy^2=1.$$
   Of course, there will also be no integral points on the $x<0$ branch since the two branches are related by $(x,y)\leftrightarrow(-x,-y)$.
2. The quadratic form $ax^2-abcxy-cy^2$ is invariant under the linear transformation
   $$T:(x,y)\mapsto((ab^2c+1)x+bcy,abx+y)$$
   in $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$.
   In particular, $T$ acts on the hyperbola, and maps integral points to integral points.
   To check whether $T$ swaps the two branches or not, we can observe that $T(a^{-1/2},-a^{1/2}b)=(a^{-1/2},0)$.
   So by continuity, $T$ acts on the $x>0$ branch of the hyperbola.
3. Let $x_{min}=\sqrt{4c/(a^2b^2c^2+4ac)}$ be the minimal $x$-coordinate on the $x>0$ branch of the hyperbola.
   Then the action of $T$ on the $x>0$ branch of the hyperbola will always increase the $y$-coordinate by at least $abx_{min}$.
   In particular, every point on the $x>0$ branch of the hyperbola can be mapped to a point satisfying $y\leq0$ and $abx+y\geq0$.
   But then $ax^2-1=cy(abx+y)\leq0$, so $x\leq a^{-1/2}$.
4. If $a>1$, then there are no integral points satisfying $0<x\leq a^{-1/2}$, so there are no integral points on the $x>0$ branch of the hyperbola.

Comment: It seems that you are using a fundamental domain for the action of $T$ on the hyperbola. Can you provide more detail here: what is the fundamental domain and why?

Comment: The fundamental domain is the interval between $(a^{-1/2},-a^{1/2}b)$ and $(a^{-1/2},0)$. One way of arguing that it is fundamental for the positive branch is to notice that $T$ must increase the $y$ coordinate by at least $abx_{\mathrm{min}}$, so with enough iterations of $T$, you must be able to reach this fundamental domain (and you can't jump over it by a monotonicity/continuity argument). I'll add more details later today.

Comment: By "interval" you mean "arc", right? At any rate, it seems that you found the "book proof" for this result.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I mean the arc between those two points.

Comment: Does your method exclude other values of $ax^2-abcxy-cy^2$ when $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Yes, I think you can show $ax^2-abcxy-cy^2$ is never less than $a$. If $ax^2-abcxy-cy^2=d$, then the arc between $(a^{-1/2}d^{1/2},0)$ and $(a^{-1/2}d^{1/2},-a^{1/2}bd^{1/2})$ is a fundamental domain. So if $d<a$, then $a^{-1/2}d^{1/2}<1$, and there are no integral points.

Comment: That's what I expected. Nice.

Comment: What is the reason that the problem "$p\neq q$, $p$ and $q$ divide $2n^2 - 1$, and $n$ divides $p - q$" admits solutions? (With a program, all triplets (p, q, n) solutions  are found up to n < 10^6).

Comment: @Noname By the same reasoning as in step 1, that problem is equivalent to the quadratic form $ax^2-bcxy-cy^2$ (with $a=2$) rather than $ax^2-abcxy-cy^2$. The nice linear transformation $T$ no longer works for this new quadratic form, so the argument breaks. General theory tells you that there will be some other more complicated linear transformation that does work, but it will have a completely different fundamental domain and may contain integral points.

Comment: thank you for the explanation, and  for your interest

Comment: I think the best way to tell this story is as follows. **Theorem.** Let $a,b,c>0$ be integers, and consider the quadratic form $P(x,y)=ax^2-abcxy-cy^2$. Then the smallest positive value of $P(x,y)$ over $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$ equals $a$. **Proof (sketch).** (I continue in the next comment.)

Comment: Let $x_0,y_0\in\mathbb{Z}$ be such that $P(x_0,y_0)>0$. Consider $(x_n,y_n):=T^n(x_0,y_0)$, where $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $T:\mathbb{Z}^2\to\mathbb{Z}^2$ is as in the original post. Note that $P(x_n,y_n)=P(x_0,y_0)>0$, hence $x_n\neq 0$. Note also that $y_{n+1}=abx_n+y_n$. One can check (by looking at $n\to\pm\infty$) that there exist both negative and positive values among the $y_n$'s. Hence there exists $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $y_ny_{n+1}\leq 0$. However, for such an $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ we have $P(x_n,y_n)=ax_n^2-cy_ny_{n+1}\geq ax_n^2\geq a$. Hence $P(x_0,y_0)\geq a$ as needed. QED

Comment: Here are further details for my proof sketch. If $\lambda_1\in(1,\infty)$ and $\lambda_2\in(0,1)$ are the two eigenvalues of $T$, then one can determine the asymptotic behaviour of $y_n$ and $y_{-n}$ for $n\to\infty$. This way one can see that $y_ny_{-n}$ is asymptotically equal to $-\lambda_1^{2n}/(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)^2$ times $ab^2P(x_0,y_0)$. In particular, $y_ny_{-n}<0$ for every sufficiently large positive integer $n$.

Comment: It's really interesting and deserves a separate thread.  Personally, I don't see the best way to ask a question about studying the quadratic form $P(x, y) = ax^2 - abcxy - cy^2$.

Comment: @Noname One can generate further facts along these lines, e.g. there is no $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $P(x,y)\in(a,a+c)$. It would be more interesting to see why $P(x,y)$, which is a natural quadratic form, is so special. In other words, it would interesting to see if there are other integral quadratic forms, not $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$-equivalent to $P(x,y)$, with similar properties. At any rate, probably MathOverflow is not the best forum to discuss such questions. New findings along these lines can be presented in blogs, personal webpages, or papers.

Comment: In hindsight, I think the easiest way to see all of these results is to use Conway's topograph. The quadratic form $P(x,y)$ has a remarkably small period. The river bends once around $a$, then back around $-c$, and then repeats (i.e., the river only bends twice per period, when for a general quadratic form the river may bend many times per period). And you can directly write out the values along the river and verify that there are no primitive values in $(a-abc-c,-c)$ or $(-c,a)$ or $(a,a+abc-c)$. (There could be a nonprimitive value in $(a,a+c)$ at $(x,y)=(2,0)$ for instance if $c$ is large).

Comment: What you say sounds very interesting, although I don't know anything about Conway's topograph. Note that $P(x,y)$ has no value in $(a,a+c)$ with $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: If $a=1$, $b=1$, $c=4$, then $P(x,y)=x^2-4xy-4y^2$ and $P(2,0)=4$ lies in $(a,a+c)=(1,5)$.

Comment: Sure, I overlooked this. What I had in mind is that every positive value of $P(x,y)$ with $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$ can be written as $ax^2+cz$ with integers $x>0$ and $z\geq 0$. And for some reason I thought that $ax^2+cz$ never lies in $(a,a+c)$. The correct statement is that it never lies in $(a,\min(4a,a+c))$.

Comment: I have created a rough plot of the action of T - https://i.stack.imgur.com/TevsT.jpg

Answer (score 2):

In contrast to the two great answers already given, I thought it would be interesting to try an approach using Pell's equation and continued fractions only.

---

**Before I do so I'd like to note that Theorem 2 of the paper
*Stolt, Bengt*, [**On a Diophantine equation of the second degree**](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02589430), Ark. Mat. 3, 381-390 (1957). [ZBL0077.05002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0077.05002).
completely solves the problem and actually proves the stronger condition that the minimum positive value of the form over the integers is $a$.**

I found this in the paper *Matthews, Keith R.; Robertson, John P.; Srinivasan, Anitha*, [**On fundamental solutions of binary quadratic form equations**](https://doi.org/10.4064/aa169-3-4), Acta Arith. 169, No. 3, 291-299 (2015). [ZBL1418.11050](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1418.11050). which refines Stolt's bounds to give a complete characterisation of the fundamental solutions.

Very Briefly the theorem states that if $(u,v)$ is a fundamental solution to $Au^2 + Buv + cv^2= -N$ with $A$ and $N$ positive integers and $D=B^2-4AC$ a positive integer not a perfect square then if $(x_1,y_1)$ is a fundamental solution to $x_1^2-Dy_1^2=4$ we have the inequality $$0<v\leq \sqrt{\frac{AN(x_1+2)}{D}}.$$ To apply this to the equation $ax^2-abcxy-cy^2=N$ we multiply by $-1$ and exchange $x$ and $y$ to obtain $cx^2+abcxy-ay^2=-N$. Note also that $x=2+ab^2c$, $y=b$ is a fundamental solution to $x^2-Dy^2=4$ where in this case $D=(abc)^2+4ac$.

For a fundamental solution $x=u$, $y=v$ the inequality then becomes $$0<v\leq \sqrt{\frac{cN(x+2)}{D}}=\sqrt{\frac{cN(4+ab^2c)}{(abc)^2+4ac}}=\sqrt{\frac{N}{a}}$$ This implies that $N\geq a$.

---

**My own solution:**

As in Thomas Browning's answer, we will show that if $a>1$, $b$, and $c$ are positive integers, then $$ax^2-abcxy-cy^2=1\tag{1}$$ has no integer solutions.

The plan is to show that integer solutions to (1) give solutions to Pell's equation such as ${x'}^2-Dy^2=4a$. For most cases this gives convergents to the continued fraction for $\sqrt{D}$ where $D=a^2b^2c^2+4ac$. The convergents $x/y$ can explicitly computed, and hence the possible values of $x^2-Dy^2$. Comparing these values with the RHS of the Pell Equation gives contradictions except for 3 exceptional equations which are handled via congruence obstructions.

We first note that that $(a,c)=1$ is a necessary condition for integer solutions to exist.

From (1) we obtain by multiplying by 4a and -4c respectively and completing the square:
$${x'}^2-Dy^2=4a\tag{2}$$.  $${y'}^2-Dx^2=-4c\tag{3}$$.

Where $x'=2ax-abcy$ and $y'=2cy+abcx$.

Now for an odd prime $p$, $p|y$ and $p|x'$ implies $p|a$ from (2) and then from (1) $p|1$, so $(y,x')$ is a power of $2$. Also if $2|y$ then from (1) $ax^2$ must be odd and hence $ax$ also. Thus if $4|y$ then $x'/2=ax-abcy/2$ is odd. Thus

$$(y,x')=1  \textrm{ or } 2.$$

Similarly using (3) we can show that $$(x,y')=1  \textrm{ or } 2.$$

Theorem 5.1 from Keith Conrad's notes states that if positive integers $x$ and $y$ satisfy $x^2 − Dy^2 = n$ with $|n| <\sqrt{D}$ then $x/y$ is a convergent to the continued fraction of √D.

Also the particular form of $D$ actually allow us to compute the continued fraction for $\sqrt{ D}$ explicitly and in addition, the possible values of $X^2-DY^2$ when $X/Y$ is a convergent. These are $S=\{1, 4, -4ac, -ac, 1 - ac - abc, 1 - ac + abc\}$. See lemma 1 below for details.

If $(y',x)=2$ then $X^2-DY^2=-c$, has an integer solution given by $X=y'/2$ and $Y=x/2$ with $(X,Y)=1$.

In this case, $a>1$ implies $|-c|\leq|abc|<\sqrt{D}$ and therefore $X/Y$ is a convergent to $\sqrt{D}$. Since $(X,Y)=1$ this is a contradiction since, if $a>1$, $-c$ is not in the list of possible values $S$ of $x^2-Dy^2$ where $x/y$ is a convergent to $\sqrt{D}$.

Similarly if $(x',y)=2$ then $X^2-DY^2=a$, has an integer solution given by $Y=y/2$ and $X=x'/2$ with $(X,Y)=1$. $|a|\leq |abc|<\sqrt{D}$ thus $a$ must lie in $S$ and this is only possible if $a=4$, again assuming $a>1$.

We now assume that $(y',x)=(y,x')=1$. It is possible to show that $|4a|<\sqrt{D}$ and $|-4c|<\sqrt{D}$ holds for all positive $a,b,c$ if $a>1$ and $(a,c)=1$, except for those $(a,b,c)\in\{(2,1,1),(2,1,3),(3,1,2)\}$. (See Lemma 2 below for details). Aside from these equations, we can then argue as before that if $a>1$ the only possibility for $4a$ or $-4c$ to be in $S$ is when $a=4$.

Now consider the case, $a=4$. For equation (3) we have already shown that $(x,y')=2$ leads to a contradiction. If $a=4$ then $|-4c|\leq|4bc|=|abc|<\sqrt{D}$. Now  $(x,y')=1$ and $-4c$ only lies in $S$ if $-4c=-ac\in S$ but since $abc=4bc$ is even we can exclude the value $-ac$ from $S$ as this is absent if $abc$ is even. (see Lemma 1 below)

Finally we deal with the remaining equations: $2x^2-2xy-y^2=1$, $3x^2-6xy-2y^2=1$ and $2x^2-6xy-3y^2=1$ which can be shown to have no solutions by reducing modulo 3, 5 and 3 respectively.

$\blacksquare$

---

**Lemma 1**

If $D=a^2b^2c^2+4ac$ then $\sqrt{D}$ has the following continued fraction decomposition and set of periodic values of $X^2-DY^2$:

1. $b$ is even: $[abc; b/2, 2abc]$, $\{-4ac, 1, -4ac,1,...\}$
2. $b$ is odd, $abc$ even: $[a b c; -1/2 + b/2, 1, 1, -1 + (a b c)/2, 1, 1, -1/2 + b/2, 2 a b c]$ $\{-4 a c, 1 - a c + a b c, 1 - a c - a b c, 4, 1 - a c - a b c, 1 - 
    a c + a b c, -4 a c, 1,...\}$
3. $b$ is odd, $abc$ odd: $[a b c; -(1/2) + b/2, 1, 1, -(1/2) + (a b c)/2, 2 b, -(1/2) + (a b c)/2, 1, 1, -(1/2) + b/2, 2 a b c]$ $\{-4 a c, 1 - a c + a b c, 1 - a c - a b c, 4, -a c, 4, 1 - a c -  a b c, 1 - a c + a b c, -4 a c, 1,...\}$

**Proof Sketch**

Use the standard method for computing the continued fraction of a quadratic irrational.

For example if $b$ is even:

$\sqrt{D}=abc+\sqrt{D}-abc$.

$1/(\sqrt{D}-abc)=(\sqrt{D}+abc)/4ac=b/2+(\sqrt{D}-abc)/4ac$.

$4ac/(\sqrt{D}-abc)=\sqrt{D}+abc$ etc...

$\blacksquare$

---

**Lemma 2**

If $(a,c)=1$ and $D=a^2b^2c^2+4ac$ then either $|4a|<\sqrt{D} \tag{4}$ or $|-4c|<\sqrt{D} \tag{5}$ holds for any positive $a,b,c$ with $a>1$ except for the following exceptions, $(a,b,c)\in\{(2,1,1),(2,1,3),(3,1,2)\}$

**Proof**

If $4c\leq abc$ then (5) is satisfied. Since $a\geq2$, if $b\geq 2$ (5) holds. So only $b=1$ is excluded. Also if $a\geq4$ $ab\geq4$ and so (5) again holds. Therefore we may now assume that $b=1$ and $2\leq a\leq3$ are the only possible exceptions. If $4a\leq abc=ac$ then (4) is satisfied. Therefore when $c\geq 4$ (4) holds. In total this yields $2\leq a\leq3$, $b=1$ and $1\leq c\leq3$ as possible values satisfying neither (4) nor (5). However we can use the condition (a,c)=1. to reduce this set of $(a,b,c)$'s to  $\{(2,1,1),(2,1,3),(3,1,1),(3,1,2)\}$. $(3,1,1)$ satisfies (5) since $12^2<3^2+4\times3$ therefore we are left with $\{(2,1,1),(2,1,3),(3,1,2)\}$

$\blacksquare$